# How to install node-gitteh module from npm (Nodejs 0.8.x)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, gitolite

I have NodeJS 0.8.12 installed in my Linux (Ubuntu 11.10 system, i heard there is node's module for accessing my project hosting with gitolite (node-gitteh 0.17.0). I have tried to install this module by :

```
npm install gitteh
```

But it gave me error message, and i tried to build [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/) from source, then tried again

```
npm install gitteh
```

It still gave me an error, did anyone successfully do this..? Please share with me...

Comment: If a command gives you an error message, copy it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you very much, finally i could install node-gitteh on my nodejs and ubuntu 12.04. I forgot to install dependency package CMake

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

Answer (score 2):

I installed gitteh using the following fork:

```
 $ npm install git://github.com/jmendeth/node-gitteh.git
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is you do not have the necessary ubuntu packages installed to compile native code. Try `sudo apt-get install build-essential` then retry your `npm install gitteh`.

Comment: I repeat the comment I made December 9th: "If a command gives you an error message, copy it into the question". We need to see the error message to speak intelligently about what you problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the same problem. I get this error when I npm install:

```
Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-waf configure --use-bundled-libgit2
```

[this](https://github.com/libgit2/node-gitteh/issues/28) suggests that there is incompatibility with the version of libgit2 bundled with gitteh (pulling from master rather than a known working revision). However, the suggested fix of using a forked version of the package did not work for me. Anyone else?